# Angular JS 1 - Error when add framework

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I already use Angular JS 1 in my projects and always works.
But I recieved one project that is using python and django and some pages are using angular, the page that I need to work have no angular code, then I put the call for the main script:

```
<script src="/static/angular/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=public&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.5%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dpublic%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A235%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A282)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A374%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A246)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20yc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fstatic%2Fangular%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

**Note**: I have created nothing yet, nor `app.js` neither `controller.js`

I changed for the angular no minified and the error is more especific:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'public' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: how is this relevant to python and django?

Comment: I think nothing, just told becouse the sintaxe used in page use {{ .. }} I think there some like django already have angular inside, some like that

Comment: I change to use angular no minified and get other error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module public due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'public' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what happened, someone write in a hide pag a ng-controller="public". for this, angular was saying no have this controller.